# $\sum_{i=0}^N r^\frac{1}{a+bi}$ =?

Tags: summation

Is there a formula for the sum of the series $\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^N r^{1/(a+bi)}$ similar to 
 $\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^N r^i =\frac{1-r^N}{1-r}$ ?

$a$ and $b$ are constants. Thanks for your help.

Comment: is $i$ the imaginary unit?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner It is the summation index, based on the question.

Comment: I doubt there is a formula.  For most finite sums there is no simple formula - the geometric sum is something of an exception to the general rule.

Comment: I agree with Clement although the $a+bi$ was suspicious.  I almost changed the summation index to $k$ in my edits but figured there was a small chance OP did mean complex numbers and just improperly used notation.  It's happened before on this site.  The waffling made me lose interest.. eh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Just added for your curiosity.*

As already written in comments, I do not think that there exists any closed form formula for 
$$S_n=\sum_{i=0}^n r^\frac{1}{a+bi}$$ However, we could $\color{red}{\text{approximate}}$ them considering $$I=\int r^\frac{1}{a+bx}\,dx=\int\exp\left(\frac{\log (r)}{a+b x} \right)\,dx=\frac 1b\int \exp\left(\frac{\log (r)}{y} \right)\,dy$$ which is $$I=\frac 1b\left(y\, r^{\frac{1}{y}}-\log (r)\,\text{Ei}\left(\frac{\log (r)}{y}\right)\right)$$ where appears the [exponential integral function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).

Back to $x$ and using the bounds  $$T_n=\int_0^n r^\frac{1}{a+bx}\,dx$$ write $$T_n=\frac 1b\left(\log (r) \left(\text{Ei}\left(\frac{\log
   (r)}{a}\right)-\text{Ei}\left(\frac{\log (r)}{a+b\,n}\right)\right)+(a+b\, n)
  \, r^{\frac{1}{a+b n}}-a\, r^{\frac{1}{a}}\right)$$ For illustration purposes, I give below a table for $r=\frac 12$ and for a  few values of $a,b$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
a & b & n & T_n & S_n \\
 1 & 1 & 10 & 9.22372 & 8.53167 \\
 1 & 1 & 20 & 18.7997 & 18.0937 \\
 1 & 1 & 30 & 28.5385 & 27.8274 \\
 1 & 1 & 40 & 38.3493 & 37.6355 \\
 1 & 1 & 50 & 48.2008 & 47.4853 \\
& & & & \\
 1 & 2 & 10 & 9.72945 & 9.04685 \\
 1 & 2 & 20 & 19.5080 & 18.8177 \\
 1 & 2 & 30 & 29.3740 & 28.6810 \\
 1 & 2 & 40 & 39.2776 & 38.5832 \\
 1 & 2 & 50 & 49.2022 & 48.5070\\
& & & & \\
 1 & 3 & 10 & 9.94459 & 9.27580 \\
 1 & 3 & 20 & 19.7947 & 19.1207 \\
 1 & 3 & 30 & 29.7046 & 29.0287 \\
 1 & 3 & 40 & 39.6399 & 38.9631 \\
 1 & 3 & 50 & 49.5894 & 48.9120\\
& & & & \\
 2 & 1 & 10 & 9.66759 & 8.85178 \\
 2 & 1 & 20 & 19.2687 & 18.4406 \\
 2 & 1 & 30 & 29.0171 & 28.1843 \\
 2 & 1 & 40 & 38.8329 & 37.9975 \\
 2 & 1 & 50 & 48.6875 & 47.8506\\
& & & & \\
 2 & 2 & 10 & 10.0393 & 9.22030 \\
 2 & 2 & 20 & 19.8249 & 18.9988 \\
 2 & 2 & 30 & 29.6934 & 28.8647 \\
 2 & 2 & 40 & 39.5983 & 38.7683 \\
 2 & 2 & 50 & 49.5238 & 48.6929\\
& & & & \\
 2 & 3 & 10 & 10.2102 & 9.39475 \\
 2 & 3 & 20 & 20.0637 & 19.2431 \\
 2 & 3 & 30 & 29.9747 & 29.1524 \\
 2 & 3 & 40 & 39.9106 & 39.0874 \\
 2 & 3 & 50 & 49.8605 & 49.0367\\
& & & & \\
 3 & 1 & 10 & 9.90856 & 9.04240 \\
 3 & 1 & 20 & 19.5319 & 18.6549 \\
 3 & 1 & 30 & 29.2892 & 28.4078 \\
 3 & 1 & 40 & 39.1098 & 38.2260 \\
 3 & 1 & 50 & 48.9674 & 48.0821\\
& & & & \\
 3 & 2 & 10 & 10.1998 & 9.32743 \\
 3 & 2 & 20 & 19.9920 & 19.1130 \\
 3 & 2 & 30 & 29.8630 & 28.9815 \\
 3 & 2 & 40 & 39.7692 & 38.8864 \\
 3 & 2 & 50 & 49.6955 & 48.8119\\
& & & & \\
 3 & 3 & 10 & 10.3415 & 9.46925 \\
 3 & 3 & 20 & 20.1981 & 19.3210 \\
 3 & 3 & 30 & 30.1102 & 29.2314 \\
 3 & 3 & 40 & 40.0467 & 39.1670 \\
 3 & 3 & 50 & 49.9970 & 49.1167
\end{array}
\right)$$